# Setting Boot and Mirror Disks correctly at the Solaris OBP

Tags: hardware, solaris, boot, sun

I am recovering a domain that was lost due to power outage on an Sun Fire E25K server. I know how to set the appropriate parameters at the openboot prompt using nvalias/devalias, boot etc.

However, I do not understand how one gets from the output of show-disks

```
{1a0} ok show-disks
a) /pci@1dd,600000/SUNW,qlc@1/fp@0,0/disk
b) /pci@1dd,700000/SUNW,qlc@1/fp@0,0/disk
c) /pci@1dc,700000/pci@1/pci@1/scsi@2,1/disk
d) /pci@1dc,700000/pci@1/pci@1/scsi@2/disk
e) /pci@1bd,600000/SUNW,qlc@1/fp@0,0/disk
f) /pci@1bd,700000/SUNW,qlc@1/fp@0,0/disk
g) /pci@1bc,700000/pci@1/pci@1/scsi@2,1/disk
h) /pci@1bc,700000/pci@1/pci@1/scsi@2/disk
q) NO SELECTION
Enter Selection, q to quit:
```

to the correct full disk path. I know it is basically one of the pci/scsi paths listed above, but in all instruction or examples a string of additional characters is appended to the path to specify Targets and Units but the explanation of the path construction is never given.

Could someone please explain how to construct this disk path correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link which explan the answer you are looking for:
http://www.filibeto.org/sun/lib/hardware/enterprise_4500/diskbrd_aliases.html

Answer (score 0):

Formulating the question properly here seemed to spark the right search on the Interweb. I realize I may have been over-complicating things.

Basically the probe-scsi-all command will give device information, including the very important disk unit addresses. This disk unit address then simply needs to be appended to the output from show-disks which will give the final path. Further parameters (e.g. specific partitions) are appended after the last colon.

A good OBP reference can be found here: (PDF)http://www.filibeto.org/sun/lib/hardware/obp/sun_obp_reference.pdf

This [Sun OBP Quick Reference card](http://slashzeroconf.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/sun-obp-quick-ref-part-1/) proved helpful too.